# When were the first graphical app installers created for Linux distributions

Tags: linux, history, software-distribution

Having a discussion at work with a colleague, and he is claiming graphical installers for *nix environments have only been available for the last few years, but I can't find any solid information on the topic, so I thought I'd ask.

References would be appreciated, but recalling from memory will do for any of you who have been using Linux for years.

Update :
Apologies, not installers for Linux, but installers for apps inside of Linux.

Comment: define graphical... the curses based installers are still considered "graphical" but I'm guessing you are referring to the X11/GNOME based installer

Comment: The first Linux distro I used was Fedora core 2, which had anaconda, a graphical installer. Anaconda has been around for a long time, but I am pretty sure the GUI front-end is a later edition (vs the curses front-end).

Comment: yes please h3rrmiller, I'm thinking something that perhaps lets you use a mouse to point and click.

Comment: jordanm, how many years ago?

Comment: Fedora core 2 was released almost 9 years ago.

Comment: Apologies, not installers for linux, but installers for apps.

Comment: The synaptic package manager was released in 2001 according to wikipeida.

Comment: Many packages (particularly commercial software for Linux, like Matlab) had custom graphical installers in the mid/late-1990s. That's similar to the same situation in the Microsoft world. GUI package installers are a different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synaptic package manager has always been a graphic GTK-based front end for package management. This has existed since November 13, 2001 according to wikipedia. It is likely that this is not the first graphical package manager front-end, but it proves that graphical package managers go back further than "a few years".

Comment: I was fooling around with Red Hat 6.2 lately, and it had a graphical installer already (probaly since a few versions before). Red Hat 6.0 is 1999.

Answer (score 6):

AIX has had [SMIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX_SMIT) for a long time (along with the command line version smitty)

HP-UX used to have SAM (long deprecated), introduced in 1992, which ran installs through their [posix-standardized installation](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/catalog/c701) tools. (swinstall, swlist, swcopy, etc..). In addition to the command line, SAM would run them in a gui.

Comment: I believe this question was specific to Linux.

Comment: Except the original question said "unix environments"

Comment: You are right, the question does say "*nix", while the title explicitly says "linux".

Comment: fair enough. I read one more carefully than the other.

Answer (score 1):

I remember installing Mandrake 8.0 (now Mandriva) in late August in 2001.  The app installer was graphical.  I remember it looking more Qt than gtk-based.

According to DistroWatch, Mandrake had graphical installer (both for OS and app) since 7.0, around [January 2000](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=mandriva)